# Intel 8086 processor

Tags: memory, intel, x86-16

I am taking a hardware class than involves a lab, the lab is about Intel 8086 processors and I have a lab final tomorrow. Other than the information provided in the lab, what other sources can you provide me with to study for it (done the labs, need more resources, code, slides, and experiments to try on my own machine)?

Comment: +1 for a clear question.

Comment: I disagree - far too vague.  I don't know exactly what a lab is for a hardware course.  Does the OP want information on pinouts, timings, use of the 8086 in embedded work, or how to program it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years ago (1991) there was this little program called `helppc.exe` that contains a lot of information about assembly and 8086 related stuff.

There seem to be an HTML version of that here:
http://idlebox.net/2006/helppc21/HelpPC-2.10-HTML/

The original EXE version seem to be available here:
http://magicrhesus.be/esi/esi1/LMI/
And you'll need [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1) to run it

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to cease ell studying at this point.  The time for extra material was last week at the latest.  Instead, relax, tidy up your notes and clear your mind for the task tomorrow.  Marathon runners do not add another long training run the day before the event, neither should you.